# Track two objects on the screen at the same time

Tags: 3d

I want to keep two objects visible at the same time. My current idea is to calculate a bounding box that contains the two objects and then zoom and rotate the camera so the whole box is visible, is there a different way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This article by Itay Keren excellently covers camera systems: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iNSQIyNpVGHeak6isbP6AHdHD50gs8MNXF1GCf08efg/pub?embedded=true

He explains a plethora of 2D camera techniques, along with their advantages and disadvantages. This should let you design the perfect camera for your use case.

You'd probably be most interested in zoom-to-fit, anchoring, region-focus and multi-focal camera techniques.

As he covers too much material to summarize in a small reply here, I hope this link-only reply covers what you need.

Comment: Yeah, i've seen this but my question is focused more on 3d camera systems, because there the rotation of the camera is also important. If you don't rotate you may either zoom to far away, or have the closer object obscure the farther one.

Comment: Ah I see, might be a good idea to add a little bit more context to your question explaining what you've already tried and what kind of use case you have (2D, 2.5D, 3D).